# FireStore Query sub collection

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

i have the following structure in FireStore,

- questions [collection]

  - quiz 1 [document]

    - results[collection]

I want to have questions in the questions collection, then, when a user answers a question, his/her result is stored in the question's sub collection with user's string id as the id. My problem is, how can i query to get questions a user has not answered. i.e unanswered questions are those that don't have a result with user's id as their id. Hope am clear enough on this. Thanks.[FireStore Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7Hxm.png)

```
val questionsRef = db.collection("questions")
val query = questionsRef.whereEqualTo(
        questionsRef.document().collection( "results" ).document(App.INSTANCE.appUUIDString), null)
        .limit(50).get()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to have an object in the User's record (or a separate collection indexed by userId) that lists which questions they have answered and then query those that they have not answered.  (This would require getting the list of all questions and removing those that are answered.)  You'll have to retrieve the questions one-by-one in a loop.

In a no-sql database you will end up with multiple indexes for this type of structure.

Comment: Wouldn't retrieving all questions and looping for each time for new questions cause slow performance?

Comment: if it were a frequent operation, you might want to cache them locally.  The operation is definitely slower than a single query, but a single query isn't available at this time.  I've read that it's not terrible because Firebase keeps a stream open, so it's not as bad as creating a whole REST/HTTP call each time.